# VIFM - directories of the two windows at startup

Tags: vifm

I use [VIFM](https://vifm.info/) in MS-Windows 10. Right now when I start VIFM, it opens up the VIFM install directory; something like C:/ProgramFilesMy/vifm-w64-se-0.10.1-binary in both the windows. But I would like VIFM to open up a couple of specific directories. Something like C:/ in the left window and C:/MyShortcuts in the right window. How do I specify that in my vifmrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following commands to your vifmrc file.

```
only
cd c:/
vsplit c:/MyShortcuts
```

The first command "only" will make vifm run in a single window pane mode. The second command "cd c:/"; you navigate the single window pane to your first directory. The third command "vsplit c:/MyShortcuts" will create a new window pane and will cd that new window pane into your second directory.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct approach is to add

```
cd c:/
sync c:/MyShorcuts
```

to `vifmrc`.

> **:sync [relative path]**
> change the other pane to the current pane directory or to some path relative to the current directory.